# java program for powerball lottery

Tags: java, arrays

I have to check all test cases which i have given in arrays but i am not getting perfect answer.Please help me with this question.Create a `PowerBall` class that contains:

- A field for an `int` array of size 6.
- A constructor that initializes this array with 6 random values (0-9).
- A method called `checkMatch` that takes as an argument an `int` array and returns how many numbers match the class's `int` array. To match, the same numbers must be in the same position.

Write a main class which asks to user to enter 6 numbers as their lottery ticket and store it in an array. Then create a `PowerBall` object and give the user's ticket to the `checkMatch` method. Then figure out the amount won based on the return value.

The winnings are determined as follows:

- If 0 numbers match, no winnings
- If 1 number matches, win $4
- If 2 numbers match, win $7
- If 3 numbers match, win $100
- If 4 numbers match, win $10,000
- If 5 numbers match, win $1 Million
- If all 6 numbers match, win Grand Prize of $450 Million

Output the user's lottery ticket, the powerball numbers, how many matched, and the amount of money won.

```
class PowerBall {

    /*
     * ALL PRIVATE DATA BELOW
     */

    private int[] winningNumber;
    private int[] ticketNumber;
    private long cash;
    static private IntUtil u = new IntUtil();
    int matchBalCount ;
    int powerBallMatchCount;

    public int cash() {

        for (int i = 0; i < winningNumber.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ticketNumber.length; j++) {
                if (i == winningNumber.length-1 && ticketNumber[i] == winningNumber[j]) {
                    powerBallMatchCount=1;
                } else if (ticketNumber[i] == winningNumber[j]) {
                    matchBalCount++;
                }
            }

            }
        return 100;
    }


    public void check(int matchBalCount,int powerBalCount){

        System.out.println("prize---matchBalCount::"+matchBalCount+" ,powerBallMatchCount::"+powerBallMatchCount);
        if (matchBalCount == 0 && powerBallMatchCount>0) {
            System.out.println("4");
        }else if (matchBalCount == 1 && powerBallMatchCount>0) {
            System.out.println("4");
        }else if (matchBalCount == 2 && powerBallMatchCount>0) {
            System.out.println("7");
        }else if (matchBalCount == 3 && powerBallMatchCount<0) {
            System.out.println("7");
        }else if (matchBalCount == 3&& powerBallMatchCount>0) {
            System.out.println("100");
        }else if (matchBalCount == 4 && powerBallMatchCount<0) {
            System.out.println("100");
        }else if (matchBalCount == 4 && powerBallMatchCount>0) {
            System.out.println("50000");
        }else if (matchBalCount == 5 && powerBallMatchCount>0) {
            System.out.println("1lakh");
        } 


    }


    PowerBall(int[] w, int[] t) {
        winningNumber = w;
        ticketNumber = t;
        cash = 0;
     check(matchBalCount,powerBallMatchCount);
    }

    private static void test1() {
        int[] w = {4, 8, 19, 27, 24, 10};
        {
            int[] n = {4, 8, 19, 27, 24, 10};
            PowerBall x = new PowerBall(w, n);
           // x.cash();
        }
        {
            int[] n = {24, 27, 19, 8, 4, 10};
            PowerBall x = new PowerBall(w, n);
        }
        {
            int[] n = {24, 27, 19, 8, 4, 5};
            PowerBall x = new PowerBall(w, n);
        }
        {
            int[] n = {124, 127, 119, 18, 14, 10};
            PowerBall x = new PowerBall(w, n);
        }
        {
            int[] n = {124, 127, 119, 18, 14, 5};
            PowerBall x = new PowerBall(w, n);
        }
        {
            int[] n = {124, 127, 119, 18, 14};
            PowerBall x = new PowerBall(w, n);
        }
        {
            int[] n = {124, 124, 19, 119, 18, 14};
            PowerBall x = new PowerBall(w, n);
        }
    }

    private static void testRandom() {
        int[] w = {4, 8, 19, 27, 24, 10};
        int max = 10;
        long c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
            int[] n = u.generateRandomNumber(6, true, 1, 99);
            PowerBall x = new PowerBall(w, n);
            c = c + x.cash();
        }
        System.out.println("Out of " + max + " times you win " + c + "$");
    }

    private static void testBench() {
        test1();
        testRandom();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("PowerBall.java");
        testBench();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

Comment: It would help us if explain exactly what is wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have problem with my check method..its not taking value of matchBalcount  and powerBallMatch count..

Comment: You are not following the assignment's instructions. First, it told you to create a method called `checkMatch`, not `check`. Second, it told you that the `checkMatch` method should accept as a parameter an array of `int`. That is, `int[]`. Instead, you are passing two int parameters. I suggest you carefully read the instructions and follow them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to count the number of matches.

```
 public int checkMatch(int [] userTicket)
        {

            int currIndex = 0; 
            int amountNumsMatching = 0; 

            if(userTicket.length == this.ticketNumber.length)
            {
                for (currIndex = 0; currIndex < this.ticketNumber.length; currIndex++)
                {
                    if(this.ticketNumber[currIndex] == userTicket[currIndex])
                    {
                        amountNumsMatching++; 
                    }

                }
            }

            return amountNumsMatching; 

        }
```